# Not able to get an responsive SVG image mask to work in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, responsive

I try to mask an image in Firefox with SVG. The image is responsive, so the mask should be responsive too.

With a simple SVG circle mask and the attributes `maskUnits="objectBoundingBox"` and `maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"` the SVG mask works as expected. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrfvqcwL/13/).

But when I export my path from Illustrator and include it the same way as the simple SVG circle mask, it does not work. 
When I remove the `maskUnits="objectBoundingBox"` and `maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"` attributes, the image is masked, but not responsive. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrfvqcwL/14/).

I try to include the `viewbox` attribute Illustrator working with, to get responsiveness back, but that wont do it.

Anyone out there who knows how to get that reponsive SVG image mask to work?

I'm using current Firefox 45.0.2 on OSX. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

please try this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/91hmcfxc/)**, though I only tested my calculator on squared SVGs (height=width), but when I tried the highest dimension value in your case 800px it worked well.

**HTML:**

```
<svg height="0" viewBox="0 0 800 500">
  <mask id="m1" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <path d="M0,0.05C0.03375,0.03,0.08625,0.00625,0.15125,0.0025,0.25375-0.0025,0.27375,0.04625,0.3775,0.04875c0.12125,0.0025,0.15-0.065,0.25375-0.0425,0.06125,0.0125,0.0675,0.04125,0.12625,0.055C0.84625,0.08375,0.9325,0.0425,0.99875,0V0.625L0,0.625V0.05Z" style="fill:white"/>
  </mask>
</svg>
<img src="https://placebear.com/800/500" id="test" alt="">
```

**CSS:**

```
#test { width: 100%; height: auto; mask: url(#m1); }
```

Please let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Thank you, ProllyGeek. This Testcase works well with your calculator. But it doesn't work when I use a more complicated mask (there are some NaN's in the SVG path), even when I use a squared SVG. This is the [original mask](https://jsfiddle.net/hrfvqcwL/17/), is there a chance to bring it through the calculator?

Comment: @Thomasz interesting I will work on this bug and fix it I hope, maybe I should upload code to github, and get people to help with it.

Comment: Do you have any news on that? I think you would save lives with your calculator when you bring it to work! Thank you for all your efforts.

Comment: @Thomasz it has been a very busy week, but I will work on it once I get to weekend, no worries :) Cheers.

Comment: Is there an Update on this? I guess I might have a too complicated mask for the calculator too...

Comment: @D.icon what are you trying to do. Maybe I can help.

Comment: @ProllyGeek I've even tried to split the lager compound-path of the mask into its sub-sections as single paths and throw them at your calculator. But it still wont work. Probably the parts are still too complex? : 
[mask im trying to use, seperated in parts](https://jsfiddle.net/jp7bx2mv/) // 
[mask as one compound path](https://jsfiddle.net/9ct7vsmb/)

Comment: @D.icon what was the output of this calc? maye I should clean up the code and open source it

Comment: @ProllyGeek The Output for the whole compound-path [is here](https://jsfiddle.net/gc1sv0pL/). A lot of NaN. With seperated parts, even the first path just calculates to "M0.58,0.52lNaN-NaNc-NaN,0-NaN-NaNZ" – It would not be a problem if I knew what exactly is calculated here, but the Internet does not yield any meaningful information, because if then I could write my orn calculator/converter. My best guess is that i calculates the relative position within that its viewport? (like px 10,10 in 0 0 200 200 would be .05 .05)

Comment: @ProllyGeek Better than a calculator would be any Software, that lets me save/convert/edit SVGs with `maskUnits` and their coordinates...

Comment: @D.icon this is a very old thing, and if I recall correctly, then you are right all it was doing is finding paths, and dividing the the values by the viewbox dimensions. I am quite busy these days, but if you are starting to build something to solve this simple issue, I can contribute. Else I would free one our, or so , and try to clean up this calc, and maybe making it reusable again. Let me know your thoughts

Comment: @D.icon I found the soruce code, and it is very old and dirty, but can absloutely give an idea of how to start: https://github.com/justgeek/svg-mask-calculator

Comment: @ProllyGeek Thank you! I guess the main issue of the calculator is that it rounds to too few decimals (2 seem to be not very good here, bc it comes down to only integers if applied on a 100x100 viewport svg.) and that it NaN's when float-values are shorted ( 0.123 -> .123). – Definitely something I'll fix if i can squeeze in so m time.
Of the shelf vector-editors seem to not be able to save in percentages, but i found a workaround: Scale the path/s down to proportionally to a 1x1px svg and add the transformation manually in the svg-code.

Comment: @ProllyGeek Used Inkscape for this, because it seems to be the only editor, wich lets me define precision properly. So, yeah, took way to much effort, but [responsive css svg masks](http://lab.illuminous-avantgarde.net/Colored_Gigs_Laser/index.html) ARE possible across all modern browsers...